# How to configure Salesforce Confetti Celebration when lead is converted to opportunity?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I need to show Salesforce Confetti Celebration when lead is converted like when we complete trailhead badges. We are converting lead from code. How to implement this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Summer'19 release Salesforce released a fetures to "*Help your teams celebrate their successes. Toss some virtual confetti when reps reach a designated path stage, for example, winning an opportunity. You can choose the frequency, such as always for those hard-won victories or only sometimes for daily occurrences. Celebrations don’t work on the status **Converted on leads**.*"

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_sales_features_core_path.htm

[image]

In Path Setting for Lead you will find one toggle button as below. "*When users reach a specific step in the path, help them celebrate their success with on-screen confetti.*". Enable it and Select the values at which you want the Confetti Celebration.

[image]
[image]